# @salesforce/i18n/timeZone returns undefined

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to get the current user's time zone code without success.
The code below is what I am using:

```
import LANG from "@salesforce/i18n/lang";
import TIME_ZONE from "@salesforce/i18n/timeZone";

export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
    lang = LANG;
    tz = TIME_ZONE;

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log("Lang is: " + lang);
        console.log("Time Zone is: " + tz);
    }
}
```

`this.lang` has the value but `this.tz` doesn't: it returns `undefined`.
I don't understand what's happening.
At the moment my only workaround is to async call `UserInfo.getTimeZone().getID()` to retrieve it without fail.

Comment: My bad. This question is flawed by an incorrect reporting of the code used. The real culprit was a mistyped name of the variable `timezone` (it was `timezone` instead of being `timeZone`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference your LWC object properties using "this." prefix.

Thus change the code to:

```
connectedCallback() {
    console.log("Lang is: " + this.lang);
    console.log("Time Zone is: " + this.tz);
}
```

I suggest "lang" was accessing a separate, global variable and just happened to look like it was working.

(Your question does mention "this." but doesn't show it in the code)

We use this successfully in our LWC implementations.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I just realized what the problem was. For the sake of the example I changed a few things including the original name of the variable used for the time zone (and of course forgot to add `this.` in the log calls...). The real problem was that my declaration was `timezone = TIME_ZONE` instead of `time__Z__one = TIME_ZONE` (z in capital letter). In the template of course I had the correct spelling with the capital Z. ‍♂️